# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space, stringBase64 to BufferedImage

Tags: java, out-of-memory, inputstream, outputstream

I Have method where is get image as string in base64 and scale it(if needed) and transform it into BufferedImage and then in ByteArrayInputStream, and after i'm loading this image into google cloud, but i have found that i'm getting OutOfMemory even if I'm not loading into goole cloud, so i have test my method `uploadJpgFromBase64`, and indeed I'm getting OutOfMemory.

My uploadJpgFromBase64:

```
    package com.myproject.model.utils.google;

import org.imgscalr.Scalr;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Base64;


public class Gcloud {

    public static String uploadJpgFromBase64(String path, String content, int width, int height) throws Exception {
        String imageDataBytes = content.substring(content.indexOf(",") + 1);
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.getDecoder().decode(imageDataBytes);
        BufferedImage image = bufferedImage(decodedString);
        int imgWidth = image.getWidth();
        int imgHeight = image.getHeight();
        if (imgWidth > width || imgHeight > height) {
            BufferedImage resize = Scalr.resize(image, width, height);
            BufferedImage newBufferedImage = new BufferedImage(resize.getWidth(), resize.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            newBufferedImage.createGraphics().drawImage(resize, 0, 0, Color.WHITE, null);
            try (ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
                ImageIO.write(newBufferedImage, "jpg", os);
                resize.flush();
                newBufferedImage.flush();
                InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
                inputStream.close();
                return "test";
            }
        } else {
            BufferedImage newBufferedImage = new BufferedImage(imgWidth, imgHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            newBufferedImage.createGraphics().drawImage(image, 0, 0, Color.WHITE, null);
            try (ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
                ImageIO.write(newBufferedImage, "jpg", os);
                newBufferedImage.flush();
                InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
                inputStream.close();
                return "test";
            }
        }
    }

    private static BufferedImage bufferedImage(byte[] decodedString) throws IOException {
        try (InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedString)) {
            return ImageIO.read(is);
        }
    }

}
```

and stack trace:

```
    [2017-10-04T11:17:26.865+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=36 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1507105046865] [levelValue: 800] [[
  2017-10-04 11:17:26 [http-listener-2(1)] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Could not complete request
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:982)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:338)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at com.myproject.rest.filter.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.kt:54)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.awt.image.DataBufferByte.<init>(DataBufferByte.java:92)
    at java.awt.image.ComponentSampleModel.createDataBuffer(ComponentSampleModel.java:445)
    at java.awt.image.Raster.createWritableRaster(Raster.java:941)
    at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createBufferedImage(ImageTypeSpecifier.java:1074)
    at javax.imageio.ImageReader.getDestination(ImageReader.java:2892)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:1082)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:1050)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1448)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1352)
    at com.myproject.model.utils.google.Gcloud.bufferedImage(Gcloud.java:54)
    at com.myproject.model.utils.google.Gcloud.uploadJpgFromBase64(Gcloud.java:24)
    at com.myproject.model.impl.DishServiceImpl.uploadDishPhoto(DishServiceImpl.kt:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy410.uploadDishPhoto(Unknown Source)
    at com.myproject.rest.controllers.json.dish.DishController.uploadDishPhoto(DishController.kt:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
]]

[2017-10-04T11:17:26.866+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=36 _ThreadName=http-listener-2(1)] [timeMillis: 1507105046866] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[dispatcher]: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.awt.image.DataBufferByte.<init>(DataBufferByte.java:92)
    at java.awt.image.ComponentSampleModel.createDataBuffer(ComponentSampleModel.java:445)
    at java.awt.image.Raster.createWritableRaster(Raster.java:941)
    at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createBufferedImage(ImageTypeSpecifier.java:1074)
    at javax.imageio.ImageReader.getDestination(ImageReader.java:2892)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:1082)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:1050)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1448)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1352)
    at com.myproject.model.utils.google.Gcloud.bufferedImage(Gcloud.java:54)
    at com.myproject.model.utils.google.Gcloud.uploadJpgFromBase64(Gcloud.java:24)
    at com.myproject.model.impl.DishServiceImpl.uploadDishPhoto(DishServiceImpl.kt:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy410.uploadDishPhoto(Unknown Source)
    at com.myproject.rest.controllers.json.dish.DishController.uploadDishPhoto(DishController.kt:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
]]
```

I'm using:
Glassfish 5.20
spring 4.3.9.RELEASE
java8

In my local machine, after server restart, i'm just start using this method via rest api to load image as base64 string, and after 15-20 invokes(where i'm passing 1-2 images 3-5 mb each) I'm getting OutOfMemory.

So I assume that one of the Stream in `uploadJpgFromBase64` haven't release memory...mb, but why?

p.s.

```
at com.myproject.model.utils.google.Gcloud.bufferedImage(Gcloud.java:54) ==  return ImageIO.read(is); in bufferedImage method
```

Comment: You might want to avoid keeping copies of the `BufferedImage` in memory like that. Reuse the `image` variable, so you won't have `image`, `resize` and `newBufferedImage` in memory at the same time. Also null out `decodedString` when you're done with it.